# Using explode() as Aggregation Function

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pivot-table

How can I [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) duplicate index rows in a [`pd.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group": [1,2,2,3,1,2,3], 
    "panel": [1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "value": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
})

pd.pivot_table(df, index="group", columns="panel", aggfunc="explode")
```

However `"explode"` is not a valid aggregation function. I want to have this result

```
       value   
panel     1  2
group         
1         0  4
2         1  5
2         2  NaN
3         3  6
```

Comment: De-duplicate before pivoting: `df.assign(idx2=df.groupby(['group', 'panel']).cumcount()).pivot(index=['group', 'idx2'], columns='panel')`

Comment: I thought it was well covered in [this QA](/q/47152691/16343464), but not exactly, so I added details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't aggregate then explode, what you need is to de-duplicate the index before [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df.assign(idx2=df.groupby(['group', 'panel']).cumcount())
         .pivot(index=['group', 'idx2'], columns='panel')
      )
```

Output:

```
           value     
panel          1    2
group idx2           
1     0      0.0  4.0
2     0      1.0  5.0
      1      2.0  NaN
3     0      3.0  6.0
```

To get rid of the de-duplication level with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
out = (df.assign(idx2=df.groupby(['group', 'panel']).cumcount())
         .pivot(index=['group', 'idx2'], columns='panel')
         .droplevel(1)
      )
```

Output:

```
      value     
panel     1    2
group           
1       0.0  4.0
2       1.0  5.0
2       2.0  NaN
3       3.0  6.0
```

Intermediate:

```
# df.assign(idx2=df.groupby(['group', 'panel']).cumcount())

   group  panel  value  idx2
0      1      1      0     0
1      2      1      1     0
2      2      1      2     1  # will create a new row
3      3      1      3     0
4      1      2      4     0
5      2      2      5     0
6      3      2      6     0
```